# Compare two PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

Array1: `([0] => "Lion 1" [1] => "Cat 1" [2] => "Tiger 1" [3] => "Leopard 1")`

Array2: `([0] => "Lion 2" [1] => "Dog 2" [2] => "Tiger 2" [3] => "Leopard 2")`

Output to show:

```
            Array1    |   Array2
            ++++++++++++++++++++
            Lion 1    |   Lion 2
            Cat 1     |   ______ <-Blank row
            Tiger 1   |   Tiger 2
            Leopard 1 |   Leopard 2
Blank row -> _______   |   Dog 2
```

Comment: Which criteria are you using to determine a valid match between elements in array 1 and 2? Following your example my guess is that if the first word is the same, then it's a match. Is this correct?

Comment: @jordan arseno thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that might be able to help you:

```
<pre>
<?php
$array1 = Array("Lion 1", "Cat 1", "Tiger 1", "Leopard 1");
$array2 = Array("Lion 2", "Dog 2", "Tiger 2", "Leopard 2");

function build_map($array) {
    $map = Array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        $parts = explode(' ', $val);
        $map[$parts[0]] = $val;
    }

    return $map;
}

$map1 = build_map($array1);
$map2 = build_map($array2);

$only1 = array_diff_key($map1, $map2);
$only2 = array_diff_key($map2, $map1);
$both = array_intersect_key($map1, $map2);

foreach($both as $key => $val)
    echo $map1[$key]."\t\t".$map2[$key]."\n";

foreach($only1 as $key => $val)
    echo "$val\t\t________\n";

foreach($only2 as $key => $val)
    echo "________\t\t$val\n";

?>
</pre>
```

Its output is the following.

```
Lion 1      Lion 2
Tiger 1     Tiger 2
Leopard 1       Leopard 2
Cat 1       ________
________        Dog 2
```

As long as you have one of each animal in each array, this should work.

Comment: this is most likely my logic. my problem is i want also to show the value of array2 even does not exist in array1.

Comment: Are the two arrays always aligned or can the elements in each array be distributed in any order?

Comment: I noticed you edited the output for the code above but it actually doesn't result in that output (the `_______ Dog 2` row is not really shown).

Comment: each can be distributed in any order.

Comment: I just edited the code in order to take into account the requirement of showing all elements in both arrays. Hope it helps.

Comment: this exactly do helps. i already checked it. many thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php), [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) for further details.

You may be able to use them like this:

```
$array1 = Array(0 => "Lion 1", 1 => "Cat 1", 2 => "Tiger 1", 3 => "Leopard 1");
$array2 = Array(0 => "Lion 2", 1 => "Dog 2", 2 => "Tiger 2", 3 => "Leopard 2");

$animals1 = array_unique(str_word_count(implode(' ', $array1), 1));
$animals2 = array_unique(str_word_count(implode(' ', $array2), 1));

# Compare the two arrays.
$intersect = array_intersect($animals1, $animals2);

# Check if there's a match.
if (count($intersect)) {
   # found a match
}
```